# Can moving overseas invalidate travel insurance?

Tags: insurance, travel

I'm currently covered by a family travel insurance policy which was taken out 2months before I moved abroad to the Netherlands of which I'm not a registered resident. I'm still a UK & Irish citizen.

I'm going to comb through the policy once I find it but on the off-chance I can't find anything in there which relates to this I thought it wise to ask here to see if this is universally accepted or declined and what other people's experiences are. I'm also curious as to whether time spend in my home, or host country is covered.

Comment: what does the policy protect against: loss of luggage, missed vacation due to illness, medial bills...Also is there a specific time frame?

Comment: Everyone's insurance policy has the potential to be different/unique. So I think the best answer would be to read your policy.

Comment: Even if you are covered now, things may change with Brexit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each insurance policy is different, and nobody can tell what yours says except you. However it is very normal that travel insurance doesn't cover you for moves abroad (i.e. living somewhere else), and also that it assumes you are still living where you were when you bought it. In that case time spent in your home country would also not be covered. Citizenship is irrelevant.

The only way to know for sure is to talk to the insurance company.